# How to define a function that returns a string outside a struct it was declared in

Tags: c++, string, c++11, struct

I am having trouble getting my code to work, and not sure how to solve this problem.

```
#include <string>
struct car{
std::string car_name;
std::string get_name(void);
};

car::std::string get_name(){
return car_name;
}
```

Gives me error " error: 'std' in 'struct car' does not name a type car::std::string get_name(void)"

Comment: `std::string get_name(){` The namespace is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be declaring it as:

```
std::string car::get_name() {
  return car_name;
}
```

This is because, `get_name()` is part of `struct car`. And `std::string` is a different entity from `car`. `string` is part of `namespace std`.

Comment: Okay that solves it. Thank you so much, spent way too much time on this

Comment: @Nasal, one more suggestion. Keep the name as `name` instead of `car_name`, because the variable is already referred idiomatically as `car::name`. So if `car myCar;` then `car.name` is better than `car.car_name`. :-)